# Combining linq queries with "group by"

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote two queries to find duplicates in the array

```
var groups = from item in array                 
             group item by item;
var q1 = from grp in groups
         where grp.Count() > 1
         select grp.Key;
```

Is there a way to write this in one LINQ query? I know I can use method calls

```
array.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() > 0).Select(g => g.Key)
```

, but I'm curious if it is possible to use LINQ syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it looks like this:

```
var duplicateItems = from item in array
                     group item by item into grp
                     where grp.Count() > 1
                     select grp.Key;
```

The key to combining the queries is the [into](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311045%28VS.90%29.aspx) keyword.